# Search for campaign groups using LinkedIn Ads API always return 400 Bad Request

Tags: linkedin-api

Using LinkedIn Ads API document on this page -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-campaign-groups#search-for-campaign-groups

If I search for campaign groups with completed status, it will always return 400 Bad Request with following message

```
{
    "message": "{field=ID, order=ASCENDING} does not provide a valid value for sort.field for CampaignGroupSort. The acceptable values for field: ID,ACCOUNT,NAME",
    "status": 400
}
```

As you can see from the message itself, I've already used `ID` as sort's field. Following is a request url that causing error

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignGroupsV2?q=search&sort.field=ID&sort.order=ASCENDING&search.status.values[0]=COMPLETED
```

However, this issue doesn't happened if I just changed `search.status.values` from COMPLETED to something else e.g. ACTIVE. Like the following request

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignGroupsV2?q=search&sort.field=ID&sort.order=ASCENDING&search.status.values[0]=ACTIVE
```

Above request returns with http status 200 with success result.

I've tried many combinations with no luck. Anyone can help please?

Comment: This sounds like an issue that LinkedIn needs to investigate. You can submit a help ticket at linkedin.zendesk.com.

Comment: @ChristopherOu Didn't know that there's zendesk channel to report issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignGroupsV2?q=search&sort.field=ID&sort.order=ASCENDING&search.status.values[0]=COMPLETD`

There is a typo in `COMPLETED` for your `search.status.values[0]`.

Comment: Thank you for spotting this typo, but problem still existed even when I sent `COMPLETED`